# AWS Predictions stream is too big

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to convert audio data, I record in my browser, via AWS Predictions into text and created the following setup:

**js Code here**

```
 // initialize refs
    const isRecording = ref(false)
    const device = ref(null)
    const recorder = ref(null)

    async function recordAudio() {
      // context.value = new AudioContext()
      // set recording state
      isRecording.value = true
      device.value = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: false,
        audio: true
      })
      await device.value.then((stream) => {
        // create recorder
        recorder.value = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
          mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=pcm'
        })
        recorder.value.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
          await convertAudio(e.data)
        }
      })
      // start
      recorder.value.start()
    }

    // called on button click
    async function stop() {
      recorder.value.stop()
      // reset recording state
      isRecording.value = false
    }

    async function convertAudio(data) {
      const audioBuffer = await new Response(data).arrayBuffer()
      const context = new AudioContext()
      await context.decodeAudioData(audioBuffer, async (res) => {
        let output = res.getChannelData(0)
        await Predictions.convert({
          transcription: {
            source: {
              bytes: output
            },
            language: 'de-DE'
          }
        })
          .then(({ transcription: { fullText } }) => console.log({ fullText }))
          .catch((err) => console.log({ err }))
      })
    }
```

The transcription works, but only if I record for ~1 second or less. Otherwise

> I get the following error: "Your stream is too big. Reduce the frame
> size and try your request again.".

Did I setup something wrong or can I downsize the stream for AWS to handle?